# Credential for Gitlab Registry in order to deploy on AWS EB Container Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm stuck on how to setup my Gitlab Pipeline in order for Amazon Elastic Beanstalk to pull an image of my application build on Gitlab and stored on our Gitlab private Docker registry.

Here what I made work as for now:

I have a Dockerrun.aws.js which is functional by being able to access my S3 file to store my credentials for Gitlab private registry.
But I encounter a problem regarding the format I need to use to store these credits, here's the error message that AWS gives me:

> Activity execution failed, because: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/organization/app/manifests/latest: denied: access forbidden
>   Failed to pull Docker image registry.gitlab.com/organization/app:latest, retrying...
>   Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/organization/app/manifests/latest: denied: access forbidden
>   Failed to pull Docker image registry.gitlab.com/organization/app:latest: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/organization/app/manifests/latest: denied: access forbidden. Check snapshot logs for details.   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
>   caused by: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/segeco/organization/app/latest: denied: access forbidden
>   Failed to pull Docker image registry.gitlab.com/organization/app:latest, retrying...
>   Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/organization/app/manifests/latest: denied: access forbidden
>   Failed to pull Docker image registry.gitlab.com/organization/app:latest: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/organization/app/manifests/latest: denied: access forbidden. Check snapshot logs for details. (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)

I generated my deploy tokens from Gitlab, but the official documentation doesn't describe how to use said deploy tokens.
Is there a way to use my deploy tokens in the file I stored on S3 to allow AWS EB to pull my application from the registry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this question.
The format i used for my JSON file was wrong.
The documentation indicates that the config file generated by the last version of Docker is not compatible with EB and that the file needs to be modified.

Comment: Please elaborate on this. I have the exact same error. I did rename it .dockercfg. Not sure what else I need to do

Answer (score 3):

Given your [GitLab Deploy Token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/), use the generated username and password and pass it to `docker login registry.gitlab.com` when prompted (or using the appropriate CLI options). This will populate your Docker `config.json` file with the information you need to upload to S3. You'll be looking for the part that looks something like this.

```
"registry.gitlab.com": {
  "auth": "some_auth_token_here"
}
```

See [Configuring Docker Environments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html#docker-images-private) for details on how to make the file you store in S3 in order to enable using images from a private repository.

Once you have that, then see [Using Images from a Private Repository](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html#docker-singlecontainer-dockerrun-privaterepo) about populating the `Authentication` section of your `Dockerrun.aws.json` file with the S3 bucket and key containing the authentication info.

Comment: Hello,
I used the official Amazon documentation, which would end up in the solution you gave to me.
The problem lies in the fact that it doesn't work.
Instead of pulling my image, Amazon prompts me the error message i posted with my question.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to name the authentication file explicitly `.dockercfg` in S3, else it didn't work.